# Creating Multiple Columns Based on Existing Columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which is similar to the following form:

```
Age Food_1_1    Food_1_2    Food_1_3    Type_1_1    Type_1_2   Type_1_3
6      a             b         a           Pr          Vit       Min
6                    b         c                       Min       Vit
6      c             c         a           Pr          Pr        Vit
7      a             a         b           Pr          Pr        Vit
7      c                       a           Pr                    Vit
8      b             b         a           Vit         Vit       Pr
```

From this dataset, I want to create following columns:

```
axPr    axVit   axMin   bxpr    bxVit   bxMin   cxPr    cxVit   cxMin
1         0       1      0        1       0       0       0       0
0         0       0      0        0       1       0       1       0
0         1       0      0        0       0       2       0       0
2         0       0      0        1       0       0       0       0
0         1       0      0        0       0       1       0       0
1         0       0      0        2       0       0       0       0
```

These numbers represent the number of times each category of Food showed up with each category of Type for each individual. All the variables in the provided data are factors.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  #Create a column with row number
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  #Get the data in long format
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Age, row),
               names_to = c('.value', 'col'), 
               names_pattern = '(.*?)_(.*)',
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  #Connvert columns to factor
  mutate(across(c(Food, Type), factor)) %>%
  #In old dplyr use mutate_at
  #mutate_at(vars(c(Food, Type)), factor) %>%
  #Count each occurrence of food and type
  count(row, Food, Type,.drop = FALSE) %>%
  #Use unite to combine columns
  unite(col, Food, Type, sep = 'x') %>%
  #Get data in wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  select(-row)


# A tibble: 6 x 9
#  axMin  axPr axVit bxMin  bxPr bxVit cxMin  cxPr cxVit
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
#2     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
#3     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     2     0
#4     0     2     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
#5     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0
#6     0     1     0     0     0     2     0     0     0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Age = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L), Food_1_1 = c("a", 
NA, "c", "a", "c", "b"), Food_1_2 = c("b", "b", "c", "a", NA, 
"b"), Food_1_3 = c("a", "c", "a", "b", "a", "a"), Type_1_1 = c("Pr", 
NA, "Pr", "Pr", "Pr", "Vit"), Type_1_2 = c("Vit", "Min", "Pr", 
"Pr", NA, "Vit"), Type_1_3 = c("Min", "Vit", "Vit", "Vit", "Vit", 
"Pr")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks @ Shah. However, the total number of 9 columns/ variables should be created. In this case, it is just creating 6 columns/variables.

Comment: @Shah. I am also getting some variables like NAxVit, xVit, xPr

Comment: @fitrat See the updated answer. It now gives 9 column for the data shared at the end of my post. Can you confirm?